# What are the best practices for large continuous integration?

Tags: architecture, continuous-integration, agile, soa

My organisation has started a continuous integration project to automate the build of their large public-facing Web site.

By "large", I mean 30+ REST services, content and integration for an external CMS, and several ASP.NET front-ends. The systems are written with a mix of Java and C# deployed to a mix of Linux and Windows Server boxes.

We work following an agile process with seven cross-disciplinary teams, all running to a weekly sprint cycle.

We have automated build and deployment of each of the individual services, but now our challenge is to automate the (currently manual) integration and final acceptance testing.

My concerns are:

- What happens when a service changes its contract and its consumers update their code, but the initial service further changes its contract? Will we /ever/ get a stable build?
- Dependency checking is a nightmare in the manual system, and I can't see it getting better in an automated system. (We use Maven with Nexus in the Java world, with plans to use Ivy; we are attempting to squeeze the .NET code into this with interesting results.)
- How deep should our tests be? How often should they run?

Comment: DONT go to Ivy!  Your hell will be worse.  I've spent six months moving 250+ modules from Ivy back into Maven and over 100 developers are much happier because of it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens when a service changes
>   its contract and its consumers update
>   their code, but the initial service
>   further changes its contract? Will we
>   /ever/ get a stable build?

It sounds to me that in addition to looking at continuous integration, you need to be looking at how you are managing your source control system. If you have different teams working on the web service and its consumers, that work could be done in a feature branch. Once the changes to the web service contract were checked in to the feature branch, the consumers of that service could be updated, and then once tests passed on that feature branch, it could be merged in to the trunk.

Tests should be run automatically every time a check in is done to trunk, and if they don't pass, the first priority should be to fix whatever broke them.

What exactly are the issues with the dependencies? Whether you are using Maven or Ivy, once you have the dependencies defined for your projects things should be pretty smooth. Continuous integration won't hurt here once you get a repeatable build working - it will help by pointing out more quickly when things are getting out of synch.

Comment: My suspicion would be that they are not properly shifting version numbers when changing contracts or using version numbers when specifying dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally been in this scenario.  This isn't an easy problem to solve.

I seriously hope your URL'S contain an API version.

General principles as follows when working in an SOA environment.
1.  Minor (incremental and non-breaking API) changes don't force a major api version.
2.  Applications must support versions N and N+1 simultaneously until all consuming applications have upgraded.
3.  It's okay to "dark-release" applications which are "ready" for version N+1 of the API, but are not yet handling version N+1 requests from consuming applications.
4.  Remember to deprecate older API versions as soon as possible.
5.  If a minor incremental change breaks a service, then there's a problem with parsing the request - certain Java un-marshalling implementations really suck at this - a Major version change might be your only way around this problem, necessarily contravening point 1.
6.  No amount of automation will make it easier to implement than good communication and planning between relevant teams.
7.  Make sure you have regression tests proving version N still works, and that version N+1 works too, in an integration environment.
8.  Graceful degradation of service is paramount.  If a downstream service is unavailable, then tell the client the request was not handled and they should re-submit later.  Any other solution will require loads more complexity in your apps - consider an Message Queue in this instance.
8.  Each component should be individually tested through the pipeline before it's released.  General rule of thumb:
   Phase 1:  Build/Unit Test / isolated integration tests.
   Phase 2.  Deploy and test using mocked downstream services.
   Phase 3.  Deploy and test in a full-integration environment.  Be aware that tests might fail if another service is being deployed.
   Phase 4.  Manual sanity check deployment in phase 3.
   Phase 5.  Performance/Security checks.
   Phase 6.  Manual acceptance of build to deploy into production.
9.  If you follow the above principles, then you'll have an easier ride into production for each of your services - it won't be without pitfalls, but you'll have a lot of bases covered.

Remember you'll need to trust your tests, so treat testing with the respect it deserves!

Comment: +1 for respecting tests. 75% of our coding time is on testing, and that seems about right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd benefit quite a lot from tests that flex the basic functionality of the app and are likely to break when service contract changes break the service's customers.

These tests (or at least a 'fast' subset of them) should be run every time you deploy your website to an integration test environment. The full set would run at least nightly.

I think you need to view the website as super-project. If someone changes a service and breaks the customers, it will cause the deployment of the website to be marked as failed. With an aggregated change log across all the projects, identifying the service and developer responsible should be relatively easy.

When you deploy, you'll usually deploy "the website" which is effectively calling the deployment process on each of the included services, content, etc. Or perhaps just the changed bits.

Basically, what this gets to is that as an organization, you make a shift to requiring that services are stable enough that they can be integrated in with everyone else's work. If that isn't possible, they get their own branch and everyone works against the previous stable version and will have integrating with a new version of the service as a high priority story in a later sprint. Hopefully the teams want to avoid that and leave backwards compatible services available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree that the selected answer is the best one because it mentions branching by feature which should be a last resort (if used at all) as it doesn't play nice with continuous integration. For some best practices I recommend the [continuous delivery](http://martinfowler.com/books/continuousDelivery.html) and [continuous integration](http://martinfowler.com/books/duvall.html) books.